# Simple for loop on a function in R-Project

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I want to create a for loop on a function, which iterates over the items of a vector. I want to produce a vector consisting of the results:

```
funk <- function(x){return (x+1)}

ul <- seq(0,1,0.001)
test1 <- NULL
for (i in ul){
    test1 <- data.frame(column = rbind(test1, funk(ul[i])))
    }
```

I get the result

```
test1
  column
1 1
```

I would like to get

```
  column
1 1
2 1.001
3 1.002
...
```

What am I doing wrong within the loop?

Comment: As you are setting test1 as null on each iteration, you'll only get the last value. Try moving `test1 <- NULL` outside of the loop

Comment: I'm sure your example is a simplified version of what you want to do but more often than not you can just use vectorization.  In your example you could just do `test1 <- data.frame(column = funk(ul))`

Comment: @FlorianGD: I tried it, but it still returned only one value.

Comment: @yPennylane You never defined S in your example code by the way.  That could be causing errors if you're using that same code on your system. I'm guessing you intended to use 'ul' instead of 'S'.

Comment: @Dason: thanks for the hint. My code doesn't cause an error. It just doesn't do what it should. I changed it though, but it's still returning something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for loops are usually discouraged, try:

```
 sapply(ul, funk)
```

if you really want to use for loops, here is the solution

```
funk <- function(x){return (x+1)}

ul <- seq(0,1,0.001)

## always create the vector first so R allocates memory 

test1 <- rep(NA, length(ul))


for (i in 1:length(ul))
  {
  test1[i] <-  funk(ul[i])
}
```

Comment: `test1 <- data.frame(column = sapply(ul, funk))` works very well. I still would like to solve it with a for loop. Maybe you would like to look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917440/integrate-with-a-vecor-or-list-as-upper-limit-r and solve it with sapply?

Answer (score 0):

Within a loop it would be:

```
funk <- function(x){return (x+1)}

ul <- seq(0,1,0.001)
test1 = list()

for (i in 1:length(ul)){
  test1[[i]] = data.frame(column= funk(ul[i]))
}
test1  = do.call("rbind", test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for the output you want, but NOT using a for loop, could be achieved by:

```
test1 <- data.frame(column=funk(ul))

head(test1)
  column
1  1.000
2  1.001
3  1.002
4  1.003
5  1.004
6  1.005
```

If you still want a for-loop, I should use:

```
for (i in 1:length(ul)){
     d <- data.frame(column=funk(ul[i]))
     if(exists('test1')) {
       test1<-rbind(test1,d)
     } else{
       test1<-copy(d)
     }
}

head(test1)
  column
1  1.000
2  1.001
3  1.002
4  1.003
5  1.004
6  1.005
```